# Network Edge color with colorbar

Tags: python, networkx, colorbar

I have a script and I want to connect the color of the edges to the color bar (jet).
How I can do this?
'''

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
positions = [(0,1),(0,0),(1,0)]
edges = [('A','B'),('B', 'C'),('C','A')]
Connection_style = ["arc3,rad=0","arc3,rad=0","arc3,rad=0"]enter code here

plt.figure('My graph problem', figsize=[4, 3])

# Create graph
G = nx.MultiDiGraph(format='png', directed=True)

for index, name in enumerate(names):
G.add_node(name, pos=positions[index])

labels = {}

layout = dict((n, G.nodes[n]["pos"]) for n in G.nodes())
nx.draw(G, pos=layout, with_labels=False, node_size=30, node_color='darkorange',width=Edge_we)


ax = plt.gca()

for edge, cs, ec in zip(edges, Connection_style, Edge_color):
    if 0<ec<=0.06:
        color = 'midnightblue'
    elif 0.06<ec<=0.12:
        color = 'mediumblue'
    elif 0.12<ec<=0.18:
        color = 'mediumblue'
    color = 'darkred'
   # ax.text(pos1[0], pos1[1], nameslist, fontsize=3)
   ax.annotate("",
            xy=layout[edge[0]], xycoords='data',
            xytext=layout[edge[1]], textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="wedge", color=color,
                            shrinkA=3, shrinkB=3,
                            patchA=None, patchB=None, relpos=(1,20),
                            connectionstyle=cs
                            ),
            )

  for nome, pos1 in zip(names, positions):
      ax.text(pos1[0], pos1[1], nome, fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')

colors=range(0, 101)
cmap=plt.cm.jet
vmin = min(colors)
vmax = max(colors)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
sm._A = []

plt.colorbar(sm,  shrink=0.9, ticks=[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100])




plt.show()
```

'''
I used the color names but I want to connect to the color bar (jet color).
Could you please let me know how I can do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing what you want, as you're testing the `ec` variable against values between 0 and 0.18, while you draw ticks at values between 0 and 100. The difference in ranges is quite extreme.

In the example code below, `ec` ranges between 0 and 0.20 are supposed, and ticks on the colorbar as percentages between those two values.

The general idea is that you use the same `cmap` and `norm` both for assigning the colors and drawing the colorbar. A `BoundaryNorm` is used to check values against a list of bounds. A `ListedColormap` is created from a list of colors.

The following code shows these ideas, which will still need to be further adapted to your situation.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import networkx as nx

names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
positions = [(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0)]
edges = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A')]
Connection_style = ["arc3,rad=0", "arc3,rad=0", "arc3,rad=0"]

plt.figure('My graph problem', figsize=[7, 5])

# Create graph
G = nx.MultiDiGraph(format='png', directed=True)

for index, name in enumerate(names):
    G.add_node(name, pos=positions[index])

labels = {}

layout = dict((n, G.nodes[n]["pos"]) for n in G.nodes())
nx.draw(G, pos=layout, with_labels=False, node_size=30, node_color='darkorange', width=1)

ax = plt.gca()

Edge_color = [0.01, 0.10, 0.20]

cmap = ListedColormap(['skyblue', 'cornflowerblue', 'navy', 'darkred'])
bounds = [0, 0.06, 0.12, 0.18, 0.20]
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=4)
for edge, cs, ec in zip(edges, Connection_style, Edge_color):
    color = cmap(norm(ec))
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=layout[edge[0]], xycoords='data',
                xytext=layout[edge[1]], textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="wedge", color=color,
                                shrinkA=3, shrinkB=3,
                                patchA=None, patchB=None, relpos=(1, 20),
                                connectionstyle=cs))
    for nome, pos1 in zip(names, positions):
        ax.text(pos1[0], pos1[1], nome, fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')

ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

cbar1 = plt.colorbar(sm, shrink=0.9, spacing='proportional', ticks=np.linspace(0, 0.20, 6), ax=ax)
cbar1.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(0.2))

plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar for edge colors]